# How do I print a control sequence in LaTeX3 with the backslash?

Tags: expl3

After at least two hours of reading the `interface3` documentation and searching this site, I still can't do this simplest of things. I need to typeset the name of a control sequence including the backslash. It's so simple in `LaTeX2e` and yet I am obviously missing something with `expl3`.

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doit}{ m }{%
  \cs_if_exist_use:N #1 
  %\tl_new:N \l_my_tl
  %\tl_set:Nn \l_my_tl {#1}
  %\token_to_str:N \l_my_tl
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% I want to do this in expl3.
\expandafter\string\csname foo\endcsname

\doit{foo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Note that `\token_to_str:N` is influenced by the value of `\escapechar` (try `\escapechar=-1 \doit \foo { bar }`). If you want to enforce the backslash you can do `\c_backslash_str \cs_to_str:N #1`.

Comment: Aha yes I see. That's good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `\token_to_str:N` on the token in question:

```
% !TEX program = lualatexmk
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\doit}{ m m }{%
  \token_to_str:N #1 % If you already have a token
  \token_to_str:c { #2 } % If you first want to build the csname
}%
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% I want to do this in expl3.
% \expandafter\string\csname foo\endcsname

\doit \foo {bar}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to use page 21 of the current `interface3` documentation. I figured there must be a nearly trivial way to do it.